# PLSQL construction a new function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a help
I'm make a function in plsql but I'm beginner

Challenge: Web a label has (imput) in less than 72hours it will not be able to leave stock
Could you help me or tell me if I'm on the right path?

```
create or replace FUNCTION CHECACODENTRADA
(
    P_CODPRO  IN VARCHAR2
)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS 
    v_database DATE;
BEGIN 
    v_database := TRUNC (SYSDATE);

    IF (p_CODPRO == '08932010','08932030','08942020','08942010','08942310','08932210')
    THEN 
        SELECT SYSDATE+3/72 FROM DUAL 
            IF SYSDATE+3/72 >=
```

Comment: What should the function do exactly? If the input code is one of the 6 specified values, what should it return? How is the date related?

Comment: What has 3/72 got to do with the requirement? 3/72 of one day is 1/24 or one hour, but you mention 72 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow. I suggest you start by writing a function *shell* and then adding functionality to it.

```
create or replace FUNCTION CHECACODENTRADA
(
    P_CODPRO  IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN 'ok';
END;
/
```

Then the next step. Add code and compile. Fix any errors and continue. If you're a complete novice then don't write large chunks of code because it could be hard to figure out what is wrong.
How are you creating these functions - are you using a proper tool like sqldeveloper ? If not... well you should. Those tools make developing pl/sql  a lot easier.

Read documentation, look for examples. pl/sql has its own syntax, don't assume that you can just *borrow* the syntax javascript or java uses... that will cause numerous errors. In your code, for example:

```
-- 2 errors in following line. 
-- 1. The "==" is not valid oracle syntax
-- 2. What is this ? '08932010','08932030'... is that a list of arguments - how would the operator "==" handle this ? What are you expecting ?
IF (p_CODPRO == '08932010','08932030','08942020','08942010','08942310','08932210') THEN 
-- the code below will not compile. You cannot "just select" in pl/sql, you need to SELECT INTO a variable.
SELECT SYSDATE+3/72 FROM DUAL
```

Some places you can start:

- the source of it all: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-640DB3AA-15AF-4825-BD6C-1D4EB5AB7715
- Google "pl/sql basics" and read up on it.
- write small blocks in pl/sql to try things out. Use the sample schema emp/dept to have sample data everyone knows. You can get a database schema on apex.oracle.com (well that is an apex workspace but in the sql workshop you can do all the pl/sql you want) or use livesql.oracle.com

Other than that, you wrote your first code and asked questions about it - so you're definitely on the right track :)

Comment: Yes I'm using 'SQL developer' 

-- 1. The "==" is not valid oracle syntax // Thanks for the explanation
-- 2.  This number are a 'codes' that useds in production
I'll see the link that you sent for me